# What is $P\times_G E$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

I know what is principal bundle and associated bundle according Wiki.But I am not understand what is $P\times_G E$ .Seemly it is bundle,but I am not sure what structure is it .

Below picture is from 224 page of [this](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947) .

> [image]

Comment: This is just the associated bundle determined by the $G$-representation $E$.

Comment: @Travis   Whether  it  is $V=(P/G) \times (E/G)$ ?

Comment: No; for one, in general the associated bundle is not trivial (and $E / G$ in general is not a smooth manifold).